# Making scale legends/labels for jquery UI slider in a fluid layout

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

A visual scale for a [JQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#default) seems such a common feature required by many use cases, yet I have not found a standard approach for making one.

My question: can this only be done via custom HTML and CSS on a case-by-case basis? If so, how do we implement the correct spacing (assuming the scale is evenly spaced, e.g. 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50) between legends in terms of `em` or `%`, but not by `px`, since the slider is embedded in a fluid layout?

Answer (score 0):

Believe my sample will help you.
[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ijekix/3/)